# Bounty Bonanaza Cross Network Promotion

Tags: discussion, events

[image: Travel.SE Great 5 Year Anniversary Bounty Bonanza]

So [we're planning on having this "event" in June](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/the-great-5-year-anniversary-bounty-bonanza), where as many high rep people as possible fling as much reputation around in bounties as possible. The idea being 1. Why not? and 2. To attract more users.

In aid of the second objective, we need to make people outside of checking TSE every day aware that the event is even happening. Obvious candidates for this are existing Stack Exchange users.

Non-beta Stack Exchange sites (except maybe SO?) have a thread in their "meta" area, called "Community Promotion Ads - 2016" where users of that site can post images that will be shown in the sidebar. [Here's the Travel one.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/community-promotion-ads-2016)

What could be done as a start for promotion is taking the image we already have to promote the event within TSE, and spread it elsewhere. As I can imagine (quite reasonably) other communities feeling annoyed or spammed by simple "drive by" posts, this should ideally be done by people who are established memebers of the community on that site (at least having a reasonable reputation count) and who personally feel that there may be some genuine interest from that site. Obvious candidate (to me) would be Aviation and Bicycles. Academia and The Workplace might also make sense.

The post in the ads promotion should look something like this:

```
[![Travel.SE Great 5 Year Anniversary Bounty Bonanza][1]][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIr0S.jpg
[2]: http://travel.stackexchange.com
```

Please post an answer here if you have submitted the image to another Stack Exchange network site. (Although others please note - this isn't a call to "brigade" upvote it)

Comment: As an aside, I'm not really high rep anywhere else, and most other places I'm even on are in beta.

Answer (score 4):

Have popped one on [Security.SE](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/community-promotion-ads-2016/2366#2366)'s Community Promotion Ads post and mentioned to the folks on Outdoors.SE (who are still in Beta so don't have Community Ads yet)

Comment: Could you either delete this ad, or replace it with a generic Travel one now?

Comment: Deleted days ago :-)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to tweet using the various Stack Exchange hash tags.  I tweeted the link to a TSE question and this happened...

[image]

The indications are that people who follow the SE/SO hash tags will pick up on it.  The question was deleted due to poor community reception, so the actual link is dead, but the dynamics of getting the word out are still valid.

Answer (score 3):

Mark created a [chat event for the Bonanza](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule). Let's make sure that the interested users register there.

I put an advert in on [Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/community-promotion-ads-2016/3335#3335) after asking StrongBad.

Comment: Could you either delete this ad, or replace it with a generic Travel one now?

Answer (score 2):

I put in an advert over at [The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3710/32964), as some crossover seems reasonable. They don't have any community adverts of their own, interestingly.

I am writing an extra paragraph to ensure that this doesn't get marked as a "trivial answer" and converted to a comment.

**This advert has now been deleted from the meta thread in question**